# How can i run a insert query script(.sql) to create tables and columns or pre populate few datas

Tags: mysql, cloud-foundry

I need to create tables and columns with some default data to run my Java web application in CloudFoundry.

I am not able to use any **MySQL client** to connect to the database ip which I received.

```
java.lang.System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
```

Is it possible to connect to the db from STS or Eclipse, or is there any client published by VMware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the VMC cli tool to create a tunnel to your MySQL service. When the tunnel is connected you can then opt to start a mysql client that will automatically connect to the instance.

Please see http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html for an example of connecting to a MySQL service on CloudFoundry.

Comment: Thank you , that helped me a lot... though i had a hard time running vmc and all those dependencies in Ruby