# What is the common practice to create db schema in Cloud Foundry?

Tags: database, cloud-foundry

I have been quested for a while for a best practice to initialize the relational database schema and pre-populated data.

There are a couple of ways to make it happen:

1. Install the cf-ex-phpmyadmin and import the data and schema thru it
2. Use the VMC cli tool to create a tunnel the service from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981512/how-can-i-run-a-insert-query-script-sql-to-create-tables-and-columns-or-pre-po)
3. If using ruby or python, use the db migration command in the manifest.yml.  However, it will be executed on each instance and every time the instance re-stages.

Which one is commonly used and most effective?

Comment: try to convince your cloudfoundry admin, that the database should be accessible from outside of cloudfoundry. Then Use any database tool, even the command line client to create the schema.

Comment: You can also have the schema created/updated by hibernate (if you are using java)

Comment: @user152468 as far as I am concerned, it is impossible to make the cloudfoundry accessible to outside. That is why I have to use another app (cf-ex-phpmyadmin) to initial the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMC is very old and is no longer supported.  I'd be surprised if it even works against a Cloud Foundry installation that has been deployed within the last couple years.  You should use the new [`cf` CLI](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli).

If you were to put the command in your manifest, you could avoid having it run on every instance if you had a conditional guard that would only run the migrations if `$CF_INSTANCE_INDEX` equals 0, however it's not always a great idea to run migrations in your start command, since there is a hard timeout on your start command, and you don't want migrations to be interrupted if they are long migrations.

A good suggestion I've heard [1] is that migrations should be handled as a separate part of your deploy process, either by [`cf ssh`](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html) or running them locally, pointed at the URL and credentials of your database service instance.

[1] credit to [Travis Grathwell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/959727/tjgrathwell) for this suggestion.